# Golang: how to generate a net/http timeout Error to perform unit test

Tags: unit-testing, go

I got a piece of code like below:

```golang
if timeoutErr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && timeoutErr.Timeout() {
    // Some code that need to test
}
```

How could I generate a error that can match the condition here so the code will flow through the if.

Comment: Just implement https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error ?

Comment: Why dont you mock the method that returns the proper value to return `timeoutErr`?

Comment: Could you guy show me some actual code, I have tried several way to implement the error interface but I keep getting compiled error. I am new to Golang so one-line instruction is a bit hard for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Error` is an interface:

```
type Error interface {
        error
        Timeout() bool   // Is the error a timeout?
        Temporary() bool // Is the error temporary?
}
```

To implement it, you'll need to do something like (untested):

```
type MyError struct {
  error
}

func (e MyError) Timeout() bool {
  return true
}

func (e MyError) Temporary() bool {
  return true
}

func (e MyError) Error() string {
  return ""
}
```

Note that you have to implement `Error()` too because `Error` embeds `error`.

Comment: I didn't know that I have to put `error` into my `MyError` struct. Thanks for your reply, my UT finally work, now.

Comment: I think the `(e Error)` is suppose to be `(e MyError)`. Since, this is the accepted answer, please update it so it will not confuse other people.